# Cycloid (Maths HL IA)

Tags: integration, derivatives, cycloid

I have chosen to investigate the fact that cycloid is a quicker path than the straight line for my HL Maths IA. 
I did my own experiment and was advised to only explain up to 'timing the fall' of the brachistochrone problem by my teacher. I did and got the equation:

$$T=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}g}
\int \frac{\sqrt{1+\left(y'\right)^{2}}}{\sqrt{y}}
dx$$

However at this point my teacher wants me to compare values I got from the experiment for both straight line and cycloid to prove that the formula works and that the cycloid is faster. Where $y$ is the height, $g$ is the gravity, and $T$ is time. The height from the experiment was 18.8 cm but I don't know how to put that into the equation. Please could someone help me evaluating that equation?

Comment: Basically, don't you just want to calculate the time it for $y=0.188$ m (lower limit of the integral) to go to $y=0$, the upper limit. (This is for $g=9.8$ m/sec$^2$.)

Comment: No because the variables are y but it needs to be integrated in terms of x (as the equation ends up with dx). If you use Legrange's calculus of variations you can integrate it into simpler terms to prove that it's cycloid curve, but it's too challenging for my level of maths therefore I want to just prove it here with the values I have.

Comment: Understood, but don't you know $y(x)$, and hence $x(y)$, so the limits of integration would be $x(.118)$ and $x(0)$. Maybe I'm just confused, but I thought you know the curve and are just integrating to get the time to traverse it. Why not provide $y(x)$ here? Then the viewers can fool with it.